# Using bootstrap for responsive web design in Ruby on rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use bootstrap to create a responsive design for my site I am building in ruby on rails. In order to get that setup I used this gem : https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails

I have a table for my users object which was created using a scaffold. I want to use the table-responsive part of bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive) so I add a div around my users table with the class table-responsive. However nothing changes when I look at my site on my mobile device.

If i inspect my elements in the browser I also see that the CSS applied to the table-responsive div is pretty much empty - so its little surprise the table is not responsive.

[image]

However I dont know why when I have correctly installed this gem and things like NavBar appear to work correctly as seen in the above image. When I look at the example on the bootstrap site their element shows specific class style info that I expect in mine :

[image]

Am I using the wrong gem? Should I be doing responsive bootstrap design differently in ruby on rails v 4?

Comment: What command did you use to generate the user scaffold?

Comment: rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string - then after that worked i added bootstrap and slightly altered my index for users to have the table-responsive div

Comment: Have you included bootstrap css and bootstrap js in your app/assets/stylesheets/application.css and app/assets/javascripts/application.js?

Comment: no both are somehow empty! Any idea what I would type to include bootstrap?

Comment: That command may have generated a file, `app/assets/stylesheets/scaffold.css.scss`, which contains some styling that could be throwing bootstrap off. Next time you generate a scaffold, I suggest using the `--skip-stylesheets` option.